# Source Assistant does not recognize SQL Anywhere OLE DB Provider

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, sap-iq

(I've Googled for hours and searched StackOverflow before posting...)

I can create an OLE DB connection to Sybase IQ using the SQL Anywhere OLE DB Provider 11 installed on my machine.

So clearly SSDT knows that the driver is there.  And the connection works.

But the SQL Anywhere OLE DB Driver isn’t listed as a source in the Source Assistant.

I can connect via ODBC, but a transfer of ODBC Sybase to ODBC SQL Server is SLOWWWWWWW!

I’m wanting to do a performance test of OLE DB Sybase to OLE DB SQL Server as a point of comparison.

So, how do I get the Source Assistant to recognize my connection manager?  And why would the new connection manager process work fine, yet the Source Assistant doesn’t recognize the connection?

Screenshots are located here:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtQzpRq7KAUEgeBKYM-sD1WQ63BjMA